# What exception error to throw when doing a Stripe coupon creation

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, stripe-payments

This is the part of the code that requires an exception name:

```
coupons = {'birthday': 20, 'special': 10, 'contributor': 25}
if request.POST['coupon'] in coupons:
        percentage = coupons[request.POST['coupon'].lower()]
        try:
            stripe.Coupon.create(duration='once', id=request.POST['coupon'].lower(),
                                          percent_off=percentage)
        except {what goes here?}:
            pass
```

I am not all that familiar with exceptions, so if you have a reference to include, that would be helpful.

Comment: I would look over this source [Errors and Exceptions Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html), this is the python docs page. Every time you have a question I would suggest to look it on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the general documentation for error handling in Python is helpful, I was really looking for the specific error handling for stripe, which is found in [Stripe API Reference - Error handling - Python](https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=python)